# Wrong filling matrix in Fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran77

I have the following problem:

I have a subroutine on [Fortran 77](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran#FORTRAN_77), which must return a one-dimensional array, D_Y. All values which are needed are transferred correctly from the main program, but three elements of the matrix D_Y (D_Y(16-18)) are set to 0.0 and I don't know why.

NDIM=18, P1 and P2 are right, all parameters, which they have in equation are right too, but their sum is always set to 0!

```
SUBROUTINE DY(Y,T,PARAM,NDIM,D_Y)
  IMPLICIT NONE
    real(8),intent(in)::Y(*)
    real(8),intent(in)::PARAM(*),T
  real(8),intent(out)::D_Y(NDIM)
  integer::D
  integer,intent(in)::NDIM
    real(8)::R,R1,R2,P1,P2
  open(18,file='kinetic2.txt',status='unknown')

  R=((Y(1)-Y(4))**2.D0+(Y(2)-Y(5))**2.D0+(Y(3)-Y(6))**2.D0)**0.5D0
  R1=((Y(1)-Y(13))**2.D0+(Y(2)-Y(14))**2.D0+(Y(3)-Y(15))**2.D0)**0.5D0
  R2=((Y(4)-Y(13))**2.D0+(Y(5)-Y(14))**2.D0+(Y(6)-Y(15))**2.D0)**0.5D0

 DO D=1,6
  D_Y(D)=Y(D+6)
 END DO

 DO D=7,9
  D_Y(D)=-(PARAM(1)*PARAM(3))*(Y(D-6)-Y(D-3))/((R)**3.D0)
 END DO

 DO D=10,12
  D_Y(D)=-(PARAM(1)*PARAM(2))*(Y(D-6)-Y(D-9))/((R)**3.D0)
 END DO

 DO D=13,15
  D_Y(D)=Y(D+3)
 END DO

 DO D=16,18
  P1=-(PARAM(1)*PARAM(3))*(Y(D-3)-Y(D-12))/((R2)**3.D0)
  P2=-(PARAM(1)*PARAM(2))*(Y(D-3)-Y(D-15))/((R1)**3.D0)
D_Y(D)=P1+P2
            write(18,*) P1,P2,D_Y(D)
 END DO
  RETURN
  END
```

Comment: is that line actually indented like that?

Comment: Minor - you aren't closing channel 18.  Why not print param, y and r1, r2 in the loop instead of wrecking your brains trying to spot what is wrong.  It will probably be obvious from the output.

Comment: Also, instead of computing R**3.0D0 in the loop, it would be more efficient to compute them outside the loop.  Doesn't spot your error but it is less things to think about.  Do these figures come up really big?

Comment: Could you post a minimum working program that shows the error? That would make it much simpler to debug your code ;-) By the way, don't use `**2.D0` - that is very difficult for the compiler to optimize! Better use `**2` or even `x*x`.

Comment: Y, R1 and R2 are right, I've already checked it. Program is working :) I don't receive any error message. Anyway, thanks all for advices.

Comment: Much of the indentation of the sample code looks suspicious. In Fortran it is especially important with proper indentation (it is far from free form (as in C-like programming languages)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your compiler is treating your code as fixed form a `D` in column 1, such as in the line

```
D_Y(D)=P1+P2
```

may be understood to be a comment.  Check your compiler documentation and options.

Comment: Whoah!!! It's working! I just added some spaces. Thank you very much!!! I must memorize this thing!